# R Convert 1D data frame to 2D data frame

Tags: r

I have a 1D data frame as input:

`A,1,B,2,C,3,D,4`

that I need to convert to a 2D data frame like that:

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
```

How do I do this? I can't use `matrix(...)` as the data frame contains non-numerical values.

[Edit] `dput` of data as requested:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
V2 = 1, V3 = structure(1L, .Label = "B", class = "factor"), 
V4 = 2, V5 = structure(1L, .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
V6 = 3, V7 = structure(1L, .Label = "D", class = "factor"), 
V8 = 4), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7", "V8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: `data.frame(matrix(t(d), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))` gets you close - you need to change the second column to numeric (i assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may subset columns from the 1D data frame using logical vectors which are recycled along the columns.

```
data.frame(x = unlist(d[ , c(TRUE, FALSE)]), y = unlist(d[ , c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
#    x y
# V1 A 1
# V3 B 2
# V5 C 3
# V7 D 4
```

Comment: This Works, thanks. Is there a more generic solution to convert into a 2D data frame with `n` columns, given a specific `n`?

Comment: I think the solution proposed by @user20650 is better than mine. Just put `ncol = n`. E.g. `d <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 1))`; `data.frame(matrix(t(d), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

The `matrix` function parameter `byrow` helps here. Then you can change the class afterwards

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(c("A",1,"B",2,"C",3,"D",4),ncol=2,byrow=T))
class(data$X1) <- "numeric"

sapply(data,class)
       X1        X2 
"integer"  "factor"
```

Comment: I'm confused. Your example works, but with my actual data it does not work. All my strings are replaced with `1` if I use `matrix(...)`

Comment: @Carsten, You feed `matrix` with a data frame, i.e. a list, and you get a list matrix. Check `str(matrix(the1Ddataframe, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))`. The 'characters' in the 1D matrix, which are of `class` `factor`, are printed as their underlying numerical representation.

Comment: I didn't realize they were all factors until you put the `dput` up.

Comment: @Mike.Gahan Me neither :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
> matrix( sapply(dat,as.character), 4, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "2" 
[3,] "C"  "3" 
[4,] "D"  "4"
```

If we can assume that the "n" that you are requestion as acolumn number is a (numeric) factor of the number of values it could be:

```
> matrix( sapply(dat,as.character), length(dat)/2, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "2" 
[3,] "C"  "3" 
[4,] "D"  "4"
```

Obviously you would need to coerce this to a dataframe if the second column needed to be numeric-class, but there was nothing in your problem description that suggests hat should be the case.